# DISTINCT ON to find min and max times

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct-on

I have tried using DISTINCT ON with posrgresql to achieve the following:
Lets say I have a table that looks like this:

```
id  time   price
1   12:00  10
1   13:00  20
1   14:00  30
```

And my goal is to create a table with only 1 row per id, that shows a column of the minimum time price and the maximum time price. Something that looks like this:

```
id  min_time_price  max_time_price
1   10              30
```

I tried using DISTINCT ON (id) but can't really get it.

Would love some help, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select t.id, tmin.price, tmax.price
from (select t.id, min(time) as min_time, max(time) as max_time
      from t
     ) t join
     t tmin
     on t.id = tmin.id and t.min_time = tmin.time join
     t tmax
     on t.id = tmax.id and t.max_time = tmax.time;
```

You can also use aggregation.  Postgres doesn't have `first()`/`last()` aggregation functions, but arrays are handy:

```
select t.id,
       array_agg(price order by time asc)[1] as min_time_price,
       array_agg(price order by time desc)[1] as max_time_price
from t
group by id;
```

Or using `first_value()` and `last_value()`:

```
select distinct t.id,
       first_value(price) over (partition by time order by time) as min_time_price,
       first_value(price) over (partition by time order by time desc) as max_time_price
from t
```